# MySQL not working on mountain lion

Tags: macos, terminal, mysql

I'm using mountain lion, I have installed MySQL.

[GUI](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

[image: mysql server]

It shows MySQL is running, but when I type

```
mysql --version
```

It gives error **"mysql: command not found"**

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and mark the answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

in .bashrc or .bash_profile file (cd ~/.bash_profile)

This will tell your terminal where to find mysql command.

Answer (score 4):

`command not found` just means that the executable you're trying to run is not found in any of the directories in your $PATH environment variable.

Try `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

The documentation links include a platform guide where it tells you that MySQL gets installed into /usr/local/, and then a symlink is created at `/usr/local/mysql` that points to this install dir. Here you can see that I've installed two versions, and that symlink was updated on the last install:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/mysql*
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   27 Apr  4  2012 /usr/local/mysql -> mysql-5.5.22-osx10.6-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  102 Apr  4  2012 /usr/local/mysql-5.5.18-osx10.6-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x  16 root  wheel  544 Mar  2  2012 /usr/local/mysql-5.5.22-osx10.6-x86_64
```

I don't recall what change I made to put /usr/local/mysql/bin into my PATH, but in my opinion, the cleanest way to do that for all users is

```
sudo sh -c 'echo /usr/local/mysql/bin > /etc/paths.d/mysql'
```

and open a new tab in Terminal to get the effect immediately.